# How to separate a list of numbers repeated in haskell?

Tags: haskell

How to separate a list of numbers repeated in haskell?

example:

separate [1,1,1,2,3,3,4] -> [[1,1,1,1],[2],[3,3],[4]]

Comment: Have you made any attempts?

Comment: It sounds like this is homework, and the policy here is to help with peoples' attempts at their work, but not actually do the work for them. Could you post what you're tried?

Comment: is not a homework I'm trying to apply discrete mathematics in haskell

Comment: @user3054972 oh, that's interesting, it sounded very much like you had to reimplement `group` or `groupBy` from scratch for some assignment. Since we now know that is not the case, could you please explain in greater detail what exactly you need, because I'm not following you.

Comment: You can find the source code of [`group`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/Data-List.html#group) in the docs likewise.

Comment: There's one 1 too much in the output of the function. I'd edit, but SO complains that my edit changes less than 6 characters.

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for the [`group`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:group) function from `Data.List`.

Comment: the problem is I have to create a separate function to the list

Answer (score 1):

The answer is `groupBy (==)`

Ignore these words, Stackoverflow requires me to type some more words

Comment: thanks for your help, but then I have to do a function that separates the list

Comment: `f = groupBy (==)`. That's a function.

Comment: `group` is the same thing as `groupBy (==)`, so `r = group`.

Answer (score 0):

I try not to answer the question, but to answer how to answer the question. I hope this helps but not too much. (edit: I assumed that this was a homework; you can tell me if you want another answer.)

Try to define the type of the function first.

```
separate :: ...
```

Think about the corner cases, like empty lists and lists with one elements.

```
separate [] = ...
separate [x] = ...
```

Then, try to define that function recursively (in terms of itself).

```
separate (x:xs) = <an expression containing separate, x, and xs>
```

Depending on your implementation details, the result of `separate [3,2,3,1]` could be `[[1],[2],[3,3]]`, `[[3],[2],[3],[1]]` (if you are using `group` which you are not supposed to), or `[[3,3],[2],[1]]`. You might need to clarify this with whomever asked you to write that function.

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html

If you're using GHCi, you can use `:m +module` to import the `module`. An example session with GHCi might look like this:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> :m +Data.List
Prelude Data.List> groupBy (==) [1,1,2,3]
[[1,1],[2],[3]]
```